# Show/hide div not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am building a forum site, for every post section, there is a comments section, so I make a link for every post to show/hide comments.

The problem is that every time I press the link, only the first comment is showing up and the rest do not. My question is, what am i doing wrong? Should i contain the id of comments on the hidden div?

```js
$(function(){
    $('.showcomments2').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("comments-section2").css("display","none");
        var TargetDiv = $(this).attr("data-target");
        $("#" + TargetDiv).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<?php 
$result_posts = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_topic=:post_topic ORDER BY DATE(post_date) ASC");
$result_posts -> bindParam(':post_topic',$topic_id);
$result_posts -> execute();
while ($row2 = $result_posts ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
  //post content here...   
          ?>
 <a class="showcomments2" data-target="comments-section2<?php echo $row2['post_id']; ?>"><p align="right"><font color=#2b2d41 size="2pt">Show Comments</font></p></a>
 <?php $comments = $conn -> prepare("SELECT uid,comment,date FROM comments WHERE topic_id=:topic_id AND post_id=:post_id ORDER BY DATE(date) ASC"); 
       $comments ->bindParam(':topic_id',$topic_id);
       $comments ->bindParam(':post_id',$row2['post_id']);
       $comments -> execute();
       while ($comments_res = $comments -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           ?>
 <div id="comments-section2<?php echo $row2['post_id']; ?>" style="display:none">
                 <ul class="replies">
        <li class="cmmnt">
          <div class="avatar"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/default.png" width="55" height="55" alt="avatar"></a></div>
          <div class="cmmnt-content" id="<?php echo $comments_res['id'] ;?> ">
          <header><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="userlink"><?php 
     $online_uid3 = $conn -> prepare("SELECT online FROM user WHERE uid=:uid");
     $online_uid3 -> bindParam(':uid',$comments_res['uid']);
     $online_uid3 -> execute();
     $online_uid_result3 = $online_uid3 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if ($online_uid_result3['online'] == "on") {
     echo '<img src="images/online.png" alt="online"> <font size="3pt">'.$comments_res['uid'].'</a><font color=#7aa74d size="3pt"> (online) </font>';
     } else {
     echo '<img src="images/offline.png" alt="offline"> <font size="3pt">'.$comments_res['uid'].'</a><font color=#B8101F size="3pt"> (offline) </font>';
     }
     ?>
       </a> - <span class="pubdate"><?php echo '<font size="2pt">'.$comments_res['date'].'</font>' ; ?></span></header>
     <div class="show"> <?php echo $comments_res['comment'] ; ?> </div>
          </div> 
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
          <?php }
                  }
                  ?>
```

Comment: The PHP code is clouding the actual markup that JavaScript would be seeing.  Can you show a minimal example of that actual markup that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: this is a capture from the site : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfSj9.png . "Comment no: 1" is only showing up, but the other comment not.

Comment: A picture of the output is not the same thing as the HTML which renders that output.  We can't see what you're not showing us.

Comment: Check that the ID for comments-section2xxxx is the exact same for the coment (all comments should have the same ID if not only the one that is being shown has the correct comments-section2xxxx assigned for the toggle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, i tried the following jquery script and i added the id of the post on the divs. I think something with the toogle method was the problem.

```js
jQuery(function(){

        jQuery('.showcomments2').click(function(){
             jQuery('.comments-section2').toggle();
        });
});
```